# Is there any advantages in serving files from a massive object instead of from a hard drive in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, memory, server

I'm curious if there's any advantages in loading my website in to a huge global object (containing file content, file names and so on..) at startup.

1. Is there a speed advantage (considering such a massive Object)?
2. Is there a maximum size of a string or an object?
3. Do the files need to be encoded?
4. How will this affect my server RAM?

I'm aware that all files will be cached and I will need to reload parts of the object whenever a file is edited.

Comment: Most web servers (and OS file systems) will simply cache web pages upon first use and that is generally more than enough and a lot simpler and manages memory automatically.  If you're using a template system, the templates will be typically be cached.  A cache rather than explicitly loading them into memory yourself has the advantage of the memory use can be managed automatically based on other memory needs in the system rather than forcing a specific memory usage.

Comment: It should be faster. You should benchmark it!

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes there is a obvious benefit: Reading from RAM is faster than reading from disk (http://norvig.com/21-days.html#answers)

2) Every time you read a file from the filesystem with Node, you get back a Buffer object. Buffer objects are stored outside of the JS heap so you're not limited by the total v8 heap size. However each Buffer has a limit of 1Gb in size (this is changing: https://twitter.com/trevnorris/status/603345087028793345). Obvious the total limit is the limit of your process (see ulimit) and of your system in total.

3) That's up to you. If you just read the files as Buffers, you don't need to specify encoding. It's just raw memory

Other thoughts:

You should be aware that file caching is already happening in the Kernel by ways of the page cache. Every time you read a file from the filesystem, you're not necessarily incurring a disk seek/read.

You should benchmark your idea vs just reading from the filesystem and see what the gains are. If you're saving 10ms but it still takes > 150ms for a user to retrieve the web page over the network, it's probably a waste of time.

Answer (score -2):

It's going to be a lot of programming work to load all of your static assets onto some sort of in-memory object and then to serve them from node. I don't know of any web frameworks that have built in facilities for this and you're probably going to poorly reinvent a whole bunch of wheels... So no; there's absolutely no advantage in you doing this.

Web servers like apache handle caching files really well, if set up to do so. You can use one as a proxy for node. They also access the file system much more quickly than node does. Using a proxy essentially implements most of the in-memory solution you're interested in.

Proper use of expiration headers will ensure that clients won't request unchanging assets unnecessarily. You can also use a content delivery network, like akamai, to serve static assets from servers closer to your users. Both of these approaches mean that clients never even hit your server, though a CDN will cost you.

Serving files isn't terribly expensive as compared to sending them down the wire or doing things like querying a database.

Use a web servers to proxy your static content. Then make sure client side caching policies are set up correctly. Finally, consider a content delivery network. Don't re-invent the wheel!

Comment: Totally harsh. But haters gonna hate.